# RSForm Pro Search form

Tags: joomla-3.x, javascript, tags, search, rsform

I have created a search form with RSForm Pro, unfortunately it isn't working.

The concept is to do a TAG Search all the Fields of the Form (Select and Radio) have values which are part of a URL which has to be build when you press on "suchen" (Fields are depending on each other and the button will only show up when all steps have been completed).

I am using this code trying to accomplish this:

```
function suchen() {
    var URLBase = "http://ego.pc-helfer.eu/index.php?option=com_tags&view=tag";
    var TrailingFixedData = "&types[0]=1";

    finalURL = URLBase + document.getElementsByClassName('value1').value +
    document.getElementsByClassName('value2').value +         
    document.getElementsByClassName('value3').value + 
    document.getElementsByClassName('value4').value + 
    document.getElementsByClassName('value5').value + TrailingFixedData;
}
```

---

But when I press "suchen" the Chrome console tells me:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: suchen is not defined

I can see the script is being loaded, but I still get this message.

url of the site: http://ego.pc-helfer.eu/produktsuche/substrattkompass

Comment: FYI `document.getElementsByClassName` returns a NodeList object. Perhaps you need to write something like this: `document.getElementsByClassName('value1')[0].value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `onclick="suchen()"` and use these lines of code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#Suchen').on('click', function() {
        // Your Code Here.
        window.location.replace(finalURL);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Nice got it to work, although at first it didn't work with document.getElementsByClassName so i had to switch to document.getElementById. Now the URL is being build properly. Now the main issue is that i don't want the form to be reset. So i will probably have to make an Ajax request or isn't this possible?

Comment: AJAX is an option. Another option is to fill the form from URL parameters via javascript or jQuery after the page is loaded. Another option is to create a plugin and fill the form in server side. You will need to write a javascript function to show all parts of the form.